# Silencing AudioContext warning around suspended mode

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I have some JS code that looks like this:

```
class AudioSample {
  constructor(volume = 1, playbackRate = 1) {
    this.context = new AudioContext();
  }

  load(arrayBuffer) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.context.decodeAudioData(
        arrayBuffer,
        buffer => {
          this.buffer = buffer;

          resolve(buffer);
        },
        reject
      );
    });
  }
  // Other stuff
}

// When the page loads
const sample = new AudioSample();

fetch('/some-sound.mp3')
  .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
  .then(arrayBuffer => sample.load(arrayBuffer));

// When a button is clicked
const play = () => {
  sample.current.pause();
  sample.current.setCurrentTime(0);
  sample.current.play();
};
```

This code works as intended; when the page loads, it fetches and prepares the sounds. When the button is clicked, the sound plays (even on the very first time).

My problem is that the following warning is logged in the Chrome console:

> The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio

This warning is a bit of a problem because I want to package up this little utility, but I don't want my NPM package to be throwing red-herring warnings!

Is there any way to tell the browser "I know, don't worry, I won't play the sound until a user interacts with the page"?

Comment: You could fetch mp3 array buffer without creating an AudioContext upon page load. Then when the user hits play create the context and call sample.load before playing the sound. I don't think there is any other way to have the warning go away

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. Yeah, I'll do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For chrome, the only way to get rid of the warning is to create the context from a user gesture.  See also the [chrome bug 943258](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=943258)

It would be nice if that bug were fixed.  As the bug says, creating a context without a gesture is not wrong.  Only resuming it without a gesture is wrong.

Comment: +1 According to the [`AudioContext()` spec](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#AudioContext-constructors) it should instantiate in "suspended" state.

Comment: Noticed a recent comment in the linked issue thread. Hopefully this will be solved sometime... currently, the AudioContext is created in `suspended` mode to spec, but the warning is printed unconditionally.

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this Chrome bug by using a separate [`OfflineAudioContext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext/OfflineAudioContext) for decoding. The `OfflineAudioContext` does not log a warning on initialization.